# slow logistic regression performance in accord.net

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, accord.net

Logistic Regression using Accord.net (http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Analysis_LogisticRegressionAnalysis.htm) takes about 5 mins compute. SAS does it in a few seconds (using single CPU core as well).

Dataset is about 40000 rows and 30 inputs.

Why is there such a difference? Does SAS use algorithm with much better complexity? Logistic regression is quite simple algorithm as I know.

Is there any other library that will do better (preferably free)?

Comment: SAS may not be free - but you get what you pay for!

Comment: I need lightweight .net library, not SAS, Matlab, etc.

Comment: Please, can you tell which outputs do you get from SAS? I would guess it is the post-processing part (to extract some particular statistics) that is taking most of the processing time. If that is the case, we can try to switch off the parts of the information extraction part that are not interesting in your case.

Comment: this is what I use with Accord:
`var regression = new LogisticRegressionAnalysis(inputs, outputs, titles.ToArray(), targetField.Title); regression.Compute(); foreach (var c in regression.Coefficients) { DS.Regressions.AddRegressionsRow(reg_id, groupKey, int.Parse(periodValRules), c.Name, c.OddsRatio, c.StandardError, c.ConfidenceLower, c.ConfidenceUpper, c.Value, c.Wald.Statistic * c.Wald.Statistic, c.Wald.PValue, targetField.Title); }`

Comment: I'm going to do comparison between R, SAS, Accord.NET and Extreme Optimization within a few days...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! From what I see, it seems you are not using the c.LikelihoodRatio values. In this case, computing the c.LikelihoodRatio is what takes most of the processing time. Basically, computing the LikelihoodRatio involves re-creating a new logistic analysis for each variable in your model without the variable in question. If you have 30 inputs, it means 31 logistic regressions are being fit whenever you call regression.Compute. Since I see not all users might be interested in this feature, I will add an option to skip it, which should save processing time.

Comment: Also, please let me know of your comparison results; I would be glad to try improving them - and any other suggestion that you might have or issue that you might encounter!

Comment: This would be a great option, Cesar! Any estimate how long will it take to implement?

Comment: BTW, we actually Stepwise Logistic Regression as well, so if you add such parameter, please add it to both regular and stepwise.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to comment out this line:

https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Statistics/Analysis/LogisticRegressionAnalysis.cs#L504

It computes some very expensive statistics that I don't need.

There is the class that can be used with the standard Accord package: https://gist.github.com/eugenem/e1dd2ef2149e8c21c37d

Answer (score 0):

I had the same expirence with multinomial logistic regression. I have made a comparison between Accord, R, SPSS and Python's Scikit. I have 30 inputs, 10 outputs and 1600+ training examples. Accord took 8 min, and the rest took 2-8 sek. Accord looks beautiful but for the multinomial logistic regression it's way to slow. My solution was that I made a small python webservice that calculates the regression and saves the result in the database.